# Why doesn't set -x work within eval within a function in fish?

Tags: fish

I ran into an issue trying to dynamically set some variables based on output of a program, in a fish function.

I narrowed my issues down to a MWE:

```
function example
    eval (echo 'set -x FOO 1;')
end
```

calling:

```
>example
>echo $FOO
```

results in no output -- ie the FOO environment variable has not been set.
How should I have done this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same thing happens in a simpler form:

```
function trythis
     set -x foo bar
end
```

If you now run `trythis` and `echo $foo`, it is not set either.  That's because fish's `-x` by itself doesn't change the scope of the variable, which is by default local to the function unless it exists globally or universally already.

Try:

```
  eval (echo 'set -gx FOO 1;')
```

Where the `g` is for global.  This makes the variable work like a normal POSIX `export`ed value.  It's interesting that it works the same way with `eval` as it would with just plain `set`; if you use that line sans `g` straight on the command line, `$FOO` is set, so `eval` and process substitution `()` have not introduced a new scope or subshell, and when executed that way within a function, *the scope of the function applies.*

Answer (score 7):

You will need to give a scope to your `set` command. Without it, the default scope is local to the function. See the [fish manual section on Environment Variables](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables) for the default rules for variable scoping

Try `set -gx FOO`.